# Integrating coupon based authentication in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, appstore-approval

I am a novice Ios programmer and this is my first ios project which is almost complete.The app is basically financial data visualization  app which shows graphs and charts of various financial data.This app has been developed mainly as a promotional one and is aimed for a particular conference attendee .Now my client want to distribute the app only to the conference attendee and this number would be maximum 200 to 300.the idea is to download the app from the app store and activate it through inserting a coupon number which is unique.I have not found any particular apple verified  way for doing this.
   So How can i implement this coupon based authentication system??

Another thing is...... in username and password based logging system do i need to keep option for  "sign up  for new user" system (when submitting for app store approval) or i can send a particular username and password as a note during app submission. If I don't implement create new used based logging system(as this app would have very limited user.....no more than 300)   will my app be rejected???

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truth is you probably can't achieve that coupon thing in your app. Consult the App Store Review Guidelines for that, but Apple hates to see apps that are limited to a particular place and/or space and that can be used only by a very small number of people.

But there is a way out of this. Take a look here - https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

Comment: thanks for your answer...can you enlighten me about my second question about username and password.......

Comment: @shishir123 there's a special field for test login and password in the iTunes Connect when you upload your build so don't worry about that. If I could help you would you vote up my answer and mark it as accepted, please?